# Why would PRAGMA schema.index_list(table-name); not show primary keys?

Tags: sqlite

According to the documentation, `PRAGMA schema.index_list(table-name);` should list all of the indexes including primary keys.

However, when I use it I only get the secondary indexes.

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_info

What would cause the primary keys to not be listed?

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmployeeKey INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarChar(25) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName nvarChar(25) NULL,
    LastName nVarChar(25) NOT NULL,
    Title nVarChar(100) null,
    EmployeeId nvarChar(50) NOT NULL,
    ManagerKey INT NULL REferences Employee(EmployeeKey),
    OfficePhone VARCHAR(15) NULL ,
    CellPhone VARCHAR(15) NULL ,
    CreatedDate DateTime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
    UpdatedDate DateTime NULL
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON Employee(EmployeeId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EmployeeKey** won't be shown as an index as it's an alias of the **rowid** column.

- The **rowid** column being inherent for all tables that are not defined as **WITHOUT ROWID** tables.
- The **rowid** column could be considered the MASTER index.

If you were to not specify `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as the PRIMARY KEY, e.g. you specified `EmployeeKey TEXT PRIMARY KEY`, then an index would be listed as SQLite is quite specific about what constitutes an alias of the **rowid** *(e.g. EmployeeKey INT PRIMARY KEY is not an alias of the rowid, so would have an index)*.

You may wish to have a look at [CREATE TABLE - Rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).